# Design approach and choice of data structures

Tags: algorithm, oop, data-structures

This is a very general question.

```
Entry in the log file is like this: 
User 1 visited Page 4 
User 3 visited Page 2 
User 7 visited Page 9 
. 
. 
. 
Design an efficient data structure which supports queries like the following: 
Which page was visited by exactly 2 users in day? 
Which page was visited by only one user exactly 2 times in a day? 
Which page was visited by ‘User 3? more than 5 times in a day?
```

What should be the general choice of data structures to solve questions of these kind as part of Design Questions (OO or algorithm design). By 'these', I mean, multiple values and multiple query formats.

Comment: @Ares : No. I am preparing for design questions for interviews and want to understand  how to approach such questions

Comment: Where does the "day" inforamtion come from? Or is there one log file per day?

Comment: @FrankPuffer: Let's say that the logs are being made in a single file with time-stamps

Comment: And how many days' worth of information do you have? Do I have to search a year's worth of logs and show you all of the pages that were visited by exactly 2 users in a single day, for the whole year? Or do these queries cover just a single day's log?

Comment: @JimMischel : It could be anything. A day or a year

Comment: Then you need to clarify your problem description. Your first query, for example, "Which page was visited by exactly 2 users in a day?" Does that mean to search the entire data set for any occurrence, or does it imply that the user will be asking for a *specific* day? Are there range queries (i.e. "Which pages were visited by more than 10 users any day in March 2016?") Without more information about the scope, you're unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: This is how the interviewer frames the question. Since the I do not know the approach to the solution, I have trouble gathering requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would use a dictionary whose keys are pages and values are a list of 2-tuples representing the user and the number of visits made by that user. But since this question is so incredibly general, it's tough to say.

For example:

`Page 4: [(User 1, 1), (User 4, 10), (User 6, 30)]`

The next visit, that number would be incremented.

This has a few advantages. Since users are visiting pages and not pages visiting users, you store one object, rather than several. You can easily get things like total page visits by adding up visits to each page.
There are a fixed number of pages and a potentially unlimited number of users.

Comment: How can you say that there is a fixed number of pages? YouTube, for example, has over a billion videos, and gets in the neighborhood of half a million videos every day. There are many sites that have hundreds of thousands or millions of pages, and are continually adding new pages. Even supposedly static sites get updates on a regular basis.